# Shell command and argument expansion in Make call function

Tags: gnu-make

I have the following Makefile:

```
dependencies=$(1) style.sty $(shell sed -rne 's/^.*\\input\{([^\}]+)\}.*$//\1.tex/p' $(1))

%.pdf: $(call dependencies,%.tex)
    @echo $^
    @mkdir -p build
    @pdflatex -output-directory build $<
    @cp build/$@ .
```

What is very troubling here is that `%.tex`, which is used inside `dependencies` twice, gets expanded properly first time, but not the second time, resulting in: `sed: can't read %.tex: No such file or directory`.

The output of `make conventions.tex` is:

```
sed: can't read %.tex: No such file or directory
conventions.tex style.sty
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Arch 
Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
[...]
```

As you can see, `%.tex` got expanded into `conventions.tex` in the first occurrence of `$(1)`, but inside `$(shell)` command it doesn't work. Why?

One answer that comes into my mind is that `$(shell)` gets expanded before `%.tex`, which sounds possibly. If so, how can I force `%.tex` expansion first? I tried the following:

```
define dependencies
   temp=$(1)
   echo $(termp) style.sty $(shell sed -rne 's/^.*\\input\{([^\}]+)\}.*$//\1.tex/p' $(temp))
endef
```

But then it hangs until `Ctrl-D` is hit almost as if `sed` got called with the last argument empty…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty close actually.

You want to expand some sort of a `$(shell)` to provide *make* with more dependencies.
Here is a pattern:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.pdf: %.tex $${tex-dependencies}
    commands-that-make-$@
```

What's going on here?

- As it is reading the makefile *make* first expands the dependency line, and sees

  `%.pdf: %.tex ${tex-dependencies}`

  (notice that `$$` has become `$`)
- *Make* now has a pattern rule which purports to be able to
  convert a `.tex` file into a `.pdf`
- You ask *make* to make `f.pdf` say (*assuming* `f.tex` already exists!)

  `$ make f.pdf`
- *Make* uses the aforementioned pattern rule.

  - `%` matches `f`
  - Due to the presence of `.SECONDEXPANSION`,
    *make* expands the dependency line a second time.
    ***Critically***,
    this time `$*` expands to whatever text matched the `%` in the rule.
  - Thus you can use `$*` inside your definition of `$tex-dependencies`.
    (By the way, all the other automatic variables are available too, things like `$@`, `$<` etc.)

Something like:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

tex-dependencies = $(shell grep -Po '\\input{\K[^\\}]+' $*.tex)

%.pdf: %.tex $${tex-dependencies}
    mkdir -p build
    pdflatex -output-directory build $<
    cp build/$@ .
```

Don't need to use `$(call)` as we would only pass in `$*` (or even `$<` or `$@`), and that's just a global variable at this point.

**NOTE** That *grep* pattern for pulling out the filenames from the `\input{}` expressions is totally untested.
It's in the right ballpark though :-)

Comment: That works great, Thank you! :) However, I tried replacing `$*.tex` in `tex-dependencies` with more elegant `$<`, but for some reason it got replaced with `f.pdf` instead of `f.tex`. Why?

Answer (score 1):

There are two different things going on in your example: first make runs through the whole makefile, encounters `$(call dependencies,%.tex)` in the prerequisites for `%.pdf` and rewrites that rule immediately. In detail: it first expands *literally* to

`%.tex $(shell sed -rne 's/^.*\\input\{([^\}]+)\}.*/\1.tex/p' %.tex)`

This is, as far as make is concerned, a string which needs further expansion - but not at the `%.tex` parts. Make syntax requires only expansion of `$`-escaped symbols, at this stage it doesn't care for the filesystem and its wildcards. You can see this by giving your string to the `info` function instead of `shell`:

```
dependencies = $(info sed -rne 's/^.*\\input\{([^\}]+)\}.*$//\1.tex/p' $(1)) $(1) style.sty $(shell sed -rne 's/^.*\\input\{([^\}]+)\}.*$//\1.tex/p' $(1))
```

Executing this:

```
    user@dogbert:~$ make
    %.tex sed -rne 's/^.*\\input\{([^\}]+)\}.*/\1.tex/p' %.tex
```

First notice that make ran this function before even considering any target at all (no replacement of the `%` with an actual target name). In scanning the makefile it came across the invocation of `dependencies` and executed it without knowing which files would ever go into this rule.
Technically it simply inserted `%.tex` for every `$(1)` it saw, plus, as an unwanted side-effect, it also replaced `$/` for the empty string because it took `$/` as variable name (if you want to pass a single `$` through a make string which is subject to expansion, you need to quote it with another `$` --> `$(shell sed -rne 's/^.*\\input\{([^\}]+)\}.*$$//\1.tex/p' $(1))` ). After this first expansion, make turned to expanding the `$(shell )` part, which means executing the shell invocation that you commanded. Notice that we are still inside the `dependencies` function. The string which is passed to the shell looks like this now:

`sed -rne 's/^.*\\input\{([^\}]+)\}.*/\1.tex/p' %.tex`

Now `sed` can't find the `%.tex` file because `%` is make's wildcard character, not the shell wildcard, and giving it to the shell will search really for `%.tex` and not for all files ending in `.tex`. Sed doesn't find it, returns an error message which is ignored by make obviously, and continues to return the now complete expansion of `dependencies` back to the calling expression, the prerequisite list of your pattern rule, which now reads:

```
%.pdf: %.tex style.sty
```

As you can see, the `shell` part of your function simply returned nothing while the rest of `dependencies` returned the values as it should.
The key here is that there didn't happen any filename expansion whatsoever - this is still a part where make calculates internally without asking from the file system.

After returning from `dependencies` kicks in the prerequisite expansion and this time its all reverse to what I've said about string expansion and the shell: in the prerequisite list, `%` is the wildcard character for the target name and the stem (the characters that match the `%`) is transferred to the prerequisite lists `%` to generate its symbols. There is still no filesystem involved as make can deduce all necessary symbols from the string it found so far. Make knows now that each `.pdf`-ending target that shall be made, depends on a `.tex`-ending prerequisite with the same name plus the common prerequisite `style.sty`.

Now to correct the error that giving `%.tex` to `sed` causes: the original intent surely was to scan the specific prerequisite file for additional dependencies (that is, scanning `foo.tex` in the rule for `foo.pdf`) and not giving `sed` the wildcard pattern `*.tex` to scan each and every `.tex` file it finds in the current directory. Therefore we must postpone the execution of the `shell` function to the time where the single targets of this pattern rule are instantiated and their specific prerequisite list is generated. While there is no special syntax in make that could accomplish this, we can use the specail target `.SECONDEXPANSION:` to this end. Every rule which comes after `.SECONDEXPANSION` will be subject to another expansion of its prerequisite list. Specifically make allows for the use of special variables like `$@` in the prerequisite list, which in the first expansion are undefined. This leads us to the following corrections:

```
dependencies=$(@:.pdf=.tex) style.sty $(shell sed -rne 's/^.*\\input\{([^\}]+)\}.*$$//\1.tex/p' $(@:.pdf=.tex))

.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.pdf: $$(dependencies)
    @echo $^
    @mkdir -p build
    @pdflatex -output-directory build $<
    @cp build/$@ .
```

The more elegant (IMHO)

```
dependencies = style.sty $(shell sed -rne 's/^.*\\input\{([^\}]+)\}.*$$//\1.tex/p' $<)

.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.pdf: %.tex $$(dependencies)
    @echo $^
    @mkdir -p build
    @pdflatex -output-directory build $<
    @cp build/$@ .
```

did not work on my make 4.0 as it inserts the target and not the first prerequisite for `$<` contrary to what the documentation says.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation of the way `make` processes makefiles. It is very instructive. :)

Comment: BTW you seem to have the same problem with `$<`I had. Which version of make do you use?

Comment: `GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`
That portion about `unknown-linux-gnu` is curious. I'm running Arch, Make being installed from the official repository.

Comment: @Sventimir Yeah I noticed the `$<` weirdness. I reckon it's a _make_ bug. Cygwin make has this problem too. `GNU Make 4.2.1 Built for x86_64-unknown-cygwin`